# The method userAccounts() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Tags: java, android

I've got a userAccounts class that declares all the variables for my user accounts. But when trying to increase the size of an arrayList of type userAccounts on a button press i get the error.

```
The method userAccounts() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}
```

The code is:

```
public class CreateAccount extends Activity {
ArrayList<userAccounts> accountArray = new ArrayList<userAccounts>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account);



    final Button buttonCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
    buttonCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            accountArray.add(userAccounts());
```

Comment: You should consider following Java standard naming conventions. Class names should start with a capital letter. The way you have it makes it look like a function inside your `Activity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, if you want to add new item to your list, you should change `accountArray.add(userAccounts())` to `accountArray.add(new userAccounts())`. 
Your variant supposes that you call some method `userAccounts()` dedicated to the listener class.